# How to plot a pandas.core.series.Series as a bar graph?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to plot a pandas series variable, which has a numeric id in one column and frequency of that id in the next column. I wish to plot these two as a bar graph with freq on the y-axis and id no. on the x-axis. However, there are too many rows, i.e. id numbers. Is there a way I can only plot the top 10 most frequently occurring ids?

executing this code - `area_count.plot.bar`
gives this error-

```
<bound method SeriesPlotMethods.bar of 
<pandas.plotting._core.SeriesPlotMethods object at 0x0000019C68029908>>
```

I tried storing the top 20 values from this series into another variable using the following code:

```
for i in range(1,20):
    f[i,:] = area_count[i,:]
```

But it showed this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-1020cb7bdfc3> in <module>
      1 for i in range(1,20):
----> 2     f[i,:] = area_count[i,:]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    909             key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
    910 
--> 911         return self._get_with(key)
    912 
    913     def _get_with(self, key):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_with(self, key)
    921         elif isinstance(key, tuple):
    922             try:
--> 923                 return self._get_values_tuple(key)
    924             except Exception:
    925                 if len(key) == 1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_values_tuple(self, key)
    966 
    967         if not isinstance(self.index, MultiIndex):
--> 968             raise ValueError('Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex')
    969 
    970         # If key is contained, would have returned by now

ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you now need the top 10 frequently occurring ids, do it by turning your series into a dataframe like:

```
x = df['id'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False).head(10).to_frame().reset_index()
x.rename(columns = {'index':'id', 'id': 'freq'}, inplace = True)
```

Now plot the graph:

```
x.plot.bar(x = 'id', y = 'freq')
```

Sample Output:

[image]